# Java generics ECLIPSE bug?

Tags: java, eclipse, generics

Is this a bug or what?

[image]

Im using Eclipse and I keep getting this warning.
Whats wrong with this...

[image]

Comment: Did you `import java.util.List`?

Comment: @NullUserExceptionఠ_ఠ yes, i did..

Comment: You've either imported something other than `java.util.List` or you're configured to use an old JDK.

Comment: T_T Thanks, I got it. conflict with java.awt.List.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Check *which* `List` class you've imported. You've probably imported `java.awt.List`.

Answer (score 6):

What you see is a compilation error, not a mere warning (a warning would not cause compilation to fail).

And no, its very unlikely to be a bug in eclipse. Probably, the type `List` really doesn't declare any type parameters, because you have imported `java.awt.List` instead of `java.util.List`.